# facebook ios sdk build fails on device, works on simulator

Tags: ios5, facebook-ios-sdk, arm7

I am trying to build an app (with ARC) that uses the facebook_ios_sdk (the latest version on github).
As recommended by Facebook, I used the build script to create a static library and then added it to the project.
Now when I build the project for an iPhone 5.1 Simulator, it works fine. However, on running it for an actual device (which is running 5.1), it gives the following build error -

```
ld: in ../facebook-ios-sdk/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the build script for static library (which was too complicated for me), or just skip the library approach:

- add the Facebook sources from SDK to your project
- if using ARC, go to "target->build phases->compile sources" and mark all the Facbook source files with the
  **--fno-objc-arc** flag

That's it, works for me.

Answer (score 1):

One work around that worked was to change the Valid Architectures from"armv6 armv7" to just armv6

Comment: @TomSöderlund: Project->Build Settings->Architectures