# Application showing linker error for facebook SDK on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api

My application is running fine on simulator without any errors. I am using facebook SDK in my application. When i try to run it on device, t\it shows me linker error. I went through some similar questions and tried their solutions like in the following links

[tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900813/facebook-ios-sdk-build-fails-on-device-works-on-simulator)

and one more solution somewhere , saying unchecking Enable OpenMP Support worked for them but i can not find this option in my xcode4.5.

```
Ld "/Users/devusa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virtual_Mirrorr-bsbznuqiwhaypbbjiftsqpwpmkdo/Build/Intermediates/Virtual Mirrorr.build/Debug-iphoneos/Virtual Mirror.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Virtual Mirror" normal armv7s
cd "/Users/devusa/Documents/Start/Virtual Mirrorr"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/devusa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virtual_Mirrorr-bsbznuqiwhaypbbjiftsqpwpmkdo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/devusa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virtual_Mirrorr-bsbznuqiwhaypbbjiftsqpwpmkdo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-F/Users/devusa/Documents/Start/Virtual Mirrorr" -filelist "/Users/devusa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virtual_Mirrorr-bsbznuqiwhaypbbjiftsqpwpmkdo/Build/Intermediates/Virtual Mirrorr.build/Debug-iphoneos/Virtual Mirror.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Virtual Mirror.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -lsqlite3.0 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework FacebookSDK -o "/Users/devusa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virtual_Mirrorr-bsbznuqiwhaypbbjiftsqpwpmkdo/Build/Intermediates/Virtual Mirrorr.build/Debug-iphoneos/Virtual Mirror.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Virtual Mirror"
```

ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/devusa/Documents/Start/Virtual Mirrorr/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

1. Update to a newer version of the Facebook API
2. Add the `armv7s` architecture to the build settings of your Facebook framework
3. Remove the `armv7s` architecture from the build settings of your app

Basically, `armv7s` is the architecture used on the iPhone 5 and iPad 4. Your app supports it but the Facebook framework you're using does not.

Comment: thank you it solved my problem but removing armv7s will cause any problem in running my application on iPhone5 and iPad4?

Comment: I shouldn't. Having said that, I put that as the third option for a reason.